# Simple byte array in Z3 (SMT)

Tags: z3, smt

I try make a simple example for checking bytes in fixed array. I read also Z3 tutorials but i can't get it working. Here is may scenario:

I have fixed byte array with length of 16: T(16)

I have these conditions to check:

```
A = (T(16) + 1) And 0x0F
T(A) = 0x76
0x01 <= A <= 0x7F
```

It mean take byte from `T(16)` add `1`, make `AND` with `0x0F`, and assign result number to variable `A`.
Now check if in array `T` on position `A` `T(A)` is number `0x76`. Also `A` can be between values `0x01` and `0x7F`.

These conditions are repeating for more positions in array, but I need get it working just for first case. The goal of this is: find right order of known bytes in fixed array based on given equations.

I try it with this script but doesn't work.

> Error: operator is applied to arguments of the wrong sort.

```
(declare-const t (Array Int Int))
(declare-const a Int)
; A = (t(16) + 1) And 0x0F
(assert (= a (bvand (+ (select t 16) 1) #x0F)))
; t(A) = 0x76
(assert (= (select t a) #x76))
(check-sat)
;(get-model)
```

Example:

on `T(16)` is value `0x14`, + 1 = `0x15`, `AND` `0x0F` = `0x05`, on `T(0x05)` should be value `0x76`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix integers and bitvectors like that and there is no need. Use bitvectors of size 8 in all cases. Don't use `Int`.

Besides that this will work.

You might find that not using arrays but only bitvectors is faster. This is something to experiment with.

Comment: Thank you, yes  you are right about types. About idea not using arrays - i can create 16  BitVec variables ... but how i can read value on X position? Case: T(A) = 0x76, Maybe some kind of **Select Case**? If A = 1 Then use T1, if A = 2 Use T2 variable? Because X is unknown ...

Comment: Something like `i == 0 ? x0 : i == 1 ? x1 : ...`. That's awkward but can be faster than using arrays because that forces Z3 to use a more general solver.

Comment: About `i == 0 ? x0` ... This can be writen by the if-then-else command **ite** ? e.g assign to value X N-th value from our values T0,T1.. 
`(assert (= X (ite (= A 0) T0 (ite (= A 1) T1 T2))) )` .... but this will be very long expression ... (i write only first 2 values from 16, just as example)

Comment: Yes, use ITE for that and yes, it's a deep chain. There is a more efficient encoding, though. You make a new variable `result` and then you assert `i == 0 implies result == x0 && i == 1 implies result == x1 && ...` etc. This is much faster in practice. I wish Z3 would not require this workaround...

Comment: i end up with this script: http://pastebin.com/9myuJaYV  (don't fit here so i put it to pastebin) but still i get **UNKNOWN** result. I think i have some lame error or definition ... Or maybe i do something wrong :(

Comment: I think that's a bug. BV logic is always decidable by Z3. Report it to the team. Try specifying the QF_BV logic manually.

Comment: You was right, it was bug that don't show where is problem. It's already fixed in nightly build. rise4fun.com use also some outdated version ...